# Solution space exists, but with introduction of objective function 'linprog' returns no solution

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am trying to solve the problem of the following form:

$\min \frac{1}{2} x'Hx + f'x$

subject to,

$Ax = b$, and $lb \leq x \leq ub$

I have utilized 'linprog' to check whether the set $Ax = b$, and $lb \leq x \leq ub$ is empty, by solving these two constraints with the empty objective function. It returns me with a solution. However, when I am using 'quadprog' to obtain the optima, it returns with no solution. I am using interior point method in both cases.

This is a pathological case, and this is why I am not posting A, B, H, and f matrices here.

---

Actually, I am trying to solve another problem of the form:

$\min \frac{1}{2} x'Px + c'x$

subject to,

$Qx = b$, and $lb \leq x \leq ub$

I have represented this problem with its KKT condition. While the equalities and bounds as a part of the KKT conditions can be easily represented by linear functions, the complementary slackness condition makes one of the constraints quadratic. Therefore, in the modified problem, I am trying to minimize the complementary slackness condition itself. It is trivial to note that, in the modified problem the optimal solution should be zero.

---

Please note that, I am doing this just to check whether I have correctly represented the KKT condition itself. I am not able to figure out why I am observing the same. I have taken the solution to the original problem and plugged it into modified problem, and I can see no constraint violation.

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: It's possible that your linear system of equations is nearly inconsistent and that different tolerances in linprog and quadprog result in different outcomes with respect to feasibility.  You could look at the "feasible" solutions returned by linprog to see just how well they satisfy the constraints.  You could also try loosening the upper and lower bounds.  Without having the problem data, it's hard to actually answer this question.